# ¿Deberíamos hacer mini-tutoriales sobre cómo obtener la información necesaria para preguntar?

Tags: discusión

Estaba revisando las preguntas y, la verdad, se ve cada una que, sinceramente, ...

Si, lo se. **Nadie** nace sabiendo, y el desarrollo de *software* no es tema *baladí*. Hay situaciones difíciles e inesperadas incluso para los profesionales.

Para alguien en sus *primeros principios*, es muy duro efectuar una pregunta adecuada. Y muchos principiantes, simplemente, **no saben cómo obtener la información necesaria**.

Voy a poner como ejemplo a uno de los lenguajes estrella del sitio: [PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)<sup>1</sup>

- Muchos **desconocen** que tiene un servidor HTTP integrado, que se invoca con la opción `-S` en la línea de órdenes.
- Aún más, ignoran que ese mismo servidor permite mostrar **mensajes en consola**, de los que es fácil hacer *copy/paste*.

  ```php
  function debugmsg( ...$args ) {
    if( php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ) {
      $out = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
      foreach( $args as $arg ) fwrite( $out, $arg )
    }
  }
  ```
- También se puede usar un depurador, con la *extensión* `XDebug`.

Insisto: No se trataría de ayuda a programar (aunque es perfectamente usable para ello), sino de **ayuda para obtener información**, que **es** muy útil para solucionar el problema, *ergo* es muy útil para indicarla **al preguntar por el problema**.

Continuando con [PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)<sup>1</sup>, haciendo uso de las herramientas indicadas anteriormente, se puede, por ejemplo:

- Obtener *volcados* directos de todo lo que se recibe del navegador.
- Otener *volcados* de todo lo que se envía al cliente.
- Mostar mensajes de error personalizados de forma fácil.
- Mostrar *trazas* simples.

**Propongo** que los usuarios con conocimientos acerca del lenguaje y las herramientas asociadas, bien en *meta* o bien en el sitio principal, publiquen preguntas auto-respondidas, mini-tutoriales, a los que poder dirigir a los nuevos usuarios (mediante comentarios) de forma que, al menos, sepan **cómo obtener información de su problema para formular correctamente una pregunta**. Preguntas del tipo `¿Cómo obtengo la máxima información sobre un problema en PHP?`.

¿Qué os parece la idea?

> <sub>**1)** Espero no ofender a nadie llamando `lenguaje` a PHP :-)</sub>

Comment: Hace unos dias les facilite a unos usuarios unos links paso a paso de JavaScript para aprender un poco mas , me vali de un libro y de preguntas del sitio, me vino la misma pregunta que a ti, pero no me atrevi a hacerla, ordenando las preguntas ya realizadas en el sitio podemos hacer un manual de muchos lenguajes (e incluso el CORS)

Comment: Sería entonces tema de *concentrar* la información disponible en un solo sitio. Fíjate en mi ejemplo con PHP, los 3 puntos que expongo están disponibles en Internet, pero, claro, antes de buscarlos *hay que saber que existen*. Una pregunta-respuesta, un comentario, y listo.

Comment: yo pregunté/respondí sobre como mostrar la consulta que esta siendo procesada con PDO y la característica de `->debugDumpParams()` que esta disponible desde PHP 7.2 esto cataloga dentro del contexto de tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201449/debugging-de-consultas-sql-en-php-var-dump-y-debugdumpparams

Comment: @shadow ¡ Justo ! Algo como eso, que permita a un OP principiante obtener, al menos, la información mínima necesaria para formular una pregunta *en condiciones*. ¿ Algo mas genérica, y con una respuesta por *aspecto*, tal vez ? Las herramientas que muestro en esta pregunta, yo las suelo usar para *depurar* el envio/recepción de mensajes en HTTP, que es un perfil distinto de lo que se aborda en tu pregunta.

Comment: igual muchos desconocen que PHP genera HTML ( es en serio ), así que si les dices que su problema no está en el PHP y que te muestren el código generado por PHP se buguean :P

Comment: Me parece una gran iniciativa. Y, aunque pienso igual que Pablo Lozano, los que no googlean ni se documentan no se tomarán la molestia de leer. Pero, SOes en un sitio para personas que buscan, leen y no tienen pereza para aprender; de modo que se ofrecería un apoyo invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que veo es que los que no se esfuerzan en buscar en Google, no se van a esforzar a buscar en SO. Veo muchas buenas primeras preguntas (no es que sean mayoría) pero se nota cuando alguien ha intentado resolver el problema e incluso cuando alguien ha intentado resolver el problema *entendiéndolo* (puede parecer obvio, pero veo mucho intentar resolver el problema atacando el resultado).

EDICIÓN: Quiero dejar claro que no me opongo a esto, estoy dispuesto a hacer una pregunta-respuesta *wiki* sobre Java o sobre Javascript con los trucos básicos para depurar y obtener información *extra* para poner en una pregunta de SO, pero no le auguro demasiado éxito.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, el que no lo intenta, no lo intenta. Pero con una pregunta/respuesta que aune las opciones, directamente se le pone un comentar (`te sugiero visitar esta respuesta ...`) y se vota para cerrar. Nos ahorramos un montón de comentarios, que hay que leer si quieres saber de que va el tema.

Comment: Respecto a la edición de la respuesta: lamentablemente, también coincido, visto el poco número de apoyos que está teniendo ... bueno, era una idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que vale la pena intentarlo.

Es posible que *(los usuarios nuevos)* no dediquen un clic a ver una página en donde puede encontrarse la respuesta a su pregunta, otros usuarios sí pueden ver esta información muy útil.

También vale la pena tener preguntas y respuestas de referencia *(como Wikis)*<sup>1</sup> para el resto de la comunidad.